# Functional In-Memory File System

Tags: c#, latex

I'd like to use an in-memory file system of some kind to make a LaTeX distribution available to a calling application independent of the physical disk. The end-goal here is automation.

I've been working with [SharpFileSystem](https://github.com/FrozenCow/sharpfilesystem). Getting the distro *into* a VFS doesn't seem to be the difficult part: it's working with the files once they're there that seems to be the trick.

Is there a straightforward way to work with `Process.Start` or some other **executing mechanism** with such file representations or is Dokan and the like the only way to accomplish this kind of task?

Comment: Two methods.  1) Use Standard Input/Output to pass files to a Process.2)  Create a virtual server using TCP class to pass files to processes.

Comment: The distro itself needs to be called, and it's in the VFS.